# Java : read an image inside a binary file (or maybe more generally, from a stream)

Tags: java, io, java-2d

I am making a java program that reads a binary file, which contains multiple images (in PNG format), and some binary data.

How can i load the images (specifically, as `java.awt.Image`'s) ? So far the only way i have found to load an image is via functions that just take a file. How can i do it from, say, an InputStream ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ImageIO#read(InputStream)` method does return a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` (which extends from `java.awt.Image`).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.InputStream-

Comment: Looks like exactly what i need, thanks ! I must have missed it when i read the ImageIO doc.